# Why does error appears with loading form 'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json'?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I have `problems loading reference 'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json': connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80.`

I read several articles in stackoverflow about this issue then I tried to solve problem by their suggested solutions. I typed in User settings

```
{   
    "http.proxy": "http://{my_login_name}:{my_password}@{proxy_of_company}:{port}/",
    "http.proxyAuthorization": null,
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": true
}
```

Also tried

```
{
    "http.proxySupport": "off"
}
```

and

```
{
    "http.proxy": "",
    "http.proxyAuthorization": null,
    "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
}
```

but it did not work.

P.s. Vscode version 1.31.0. Link also opens without problem in browser.

P.p.s. I restarted vs code and company pc, but it also did not work.

Comment: Perhaps your computer is running an application-level firewall that is blocking HTTPS requests to https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net.